# excel application methods and properties via activexobject

Tags: javascript

is there a list of methods and properties that an excel object created via

> **new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");**

has?

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

Comment: You could always print them:  `for (var key in excel) { document.body.innerHTML += key + "<br />"; }`

Comment: Try this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @aroth Since the objects created via `ActiveXObject` aren't standard Javascript objects, you cannot iterate over them in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Excel object model is fully documented on MSDN. Here is the Excel 2010 Application object. Use the links in the left navigator to view properties and members.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194565.aspx

Move up the navigator tree to Reference to see all the objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff846392.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Microsoft documentation, there are also [Typescript definitions for Excel](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/activex-excel) available on DefinitelyTyped.

You can use an editor like VS Code that can leverage Typescript definitions in Javascript to get Intellisense for these types in Javascript.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of the Typescript definitions for Excel.)